# RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuarenteedCleanup operation not executing

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `SecureString` to `String` marshaler class as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Lidgren.Network
{
public class NetSecureStringMarshaler : IDisposable
{
    #region Private Fields

    private string _String;
    private SecureString _SecureString;
    private GCHandle _GCH;

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public SecureString SecureString
    {
        get { return _SecureString; }
        set
        {
            _SecureString = value;
            UpdateStringValue();
        }
    }

    public string String
    {
        get { return _String; }
        protected set { _String = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public NetSecureStringMarshaler()
    {
    }

    public NetSecureStringMarshaler(SecureString ss)
    {
        SecureString = ss;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    void UpdateStringValue()
    {
        Deallocate();

        unsafe
        {
            if (SecureString != null)
            {
                int length = SecureString.Length;
                String = new string('\0', length);

                _GCH = new GCHandle();

                // Create a CER (Contrained Execution Region)
                RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
                try { }
                finally
                {
                    // Pin our string, disallowing the garbage collector from
                    // moving it around.
                    _GCH = GCHandle.Alloc(String, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                }

                IntPtr stringPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
                RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(
                    delegate
                    {
                        // Create a CER (Contrained Execution Region)
                        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
                        try { }
                        finally
                        {
                            stringPtr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(SecureString);
                        }

                        // Copy the SecureString content to our pinned string
                        char* pString = (char*)stringPtr;
                        char* pInsecureString = (char*)_GCH.AddrOfPinnedObject();
                        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
                        {
                            pInsecureString[index] = pString[index];
                        }
                    },
                    delegate
                    {
                        if (stringPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            // Free the SecureString BSTR that was generated
                            Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(stringPtr);
                        }
                    },
                    null);
            }
        }
    }

    void Deallocate()
    {
        if (_GCH.IsAllocated)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                // Determine the length of the string
                int length = String.Length;

                // Zero each character of the string.
                char* pInsecureString = (char*)_GCH.AddrOfPinnedObject();
                for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
                {
                    pInsecureString[index] = '\0';
                }

                // Free the handle so the garbage collector
                // can dispose of it properly.
                _GCH.Free();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Deallocate();
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

Where when the `SecureString` is set it runs `UpdateStringValue()`.
The problem is when the method is ran, the method

```
RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(
    delegate
    {
        // Create a CER (Contrained Execution Region)
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
        try { }
        finally
        {
            stringPtr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(SecureString);
        }

        // Copy the SecureString content to our pinned string
        char* pString = (char*)stringPtr;
        char* pInsecureString = (char*)_GCH.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
            pInsecureString[index] = pString[index];
        }
    },
    delegate
    {
        if (stringPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // Free the SecureString BSTR that was generated
            Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(stringPtr);
        }
    },
    null);
```

Runs but none of the code inside the method runs.

Placing a breakpoint on any of the code inside the delegates does not result in a break however placing it on the block itself breaks the code.

It seems that `RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup` is ran but none of the code inside it executed at any point

Am i using `RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup` wrong by using delegates?

Comment: Can you talk us through why you believe you need to use `ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup`?

Comment: @mjwills Its so that the `SecureString` will ALWAYS be zeroed even if there is an `Exception` that stops code execution such as a `StackOverflowException`. This would pose a security risk, as the `SecureString` will be leaked in a `StackOverflow` if `ExecuteCodeWithGuarenteedCleanup` was not used